# MATLAB - usage of knnclassify

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning

When doing:

```
load training.mat
training = G

load testing.mat
test = G
```

and then:

```
>> knnclassify(test.Inp, training.Inp, training.Ltr)

??? Error using ==> knnclassify at 91
The length of GROUP must equal the number of rows in TRAINING.
```

Since:

```
>> size(training.Inp)
ans =
          40          40        2016
```

And:

```
>> length(training.Ltr)
ans =
        2016
```

How can I give the second parameter of knnclassify (TRAINING) the training.inp 3-D matrix so that the number of rows will be 2016 (the third dimension)?

Comment: You need to clarify how your data looks like; As far as I understood, you have 2016 instances (rows) where each has 40*40 features (columns)? Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your 3D data is interpreted as 40-by-40 matrix of features for each of the 2016 instances (third dimension), we will have to re-arrange it as a matrix of size 2016-by-1600 (rows are samples, columns are dimensions):

```
%# random data instead of the `load data.mat`
testing = rand(40,40,200);
training = rand(40,40,2016);
labels = randi(3, [2016 1]);     %# a class label for each training instance
                                 %# (out of 3 possible classes)

%# arrange data as a matrix whose rows are the instances,
%# and columns are the features
training = reshape(training, [40*40 2016])';
testing = reshape(testing, [40*40 200])';

%# k-nearest neighbor classification
prediction = knnclassify(testing, training, labels);
```